# Bit Packing LZW Phrase numbers

Tags: java, compression, bit, lzw

I am currently working on a java implementation of LZW compression. So far my encoder works how it should. Reads a file and outputs phrase numbers which will be piped to the bit packer.

I now have to bit pack those phrase numbers into a file and I am unsure how to go about this process. Also we have a maximum bits set for encoding which is 20. So when the numbers being encoded exceed 20 bits needed to encode them we reset the trie and start building a new one.

So the first set of numbers we must bit pack will be 0-255
then 256-511 and so on so I know that some will be packed as 8 bits and then 9 bits and so on.

If any guidance could be given on where to start and what to look over that may help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This isn't entirely clear; what exactly is the issue with performing bit-packing?

Comment: Why? Do you have a good reason to not use [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) or [this](http://lzwcomp.sourceforge.net/) if you **need** LZW?

Comment: Sorry so basically what I need to know is how do you bit pack integers? do we need to store them inside primitive types such as an integer before writing them to a file?

Answer (score 3):

LZW compression usually starts out with a bit count one above the size of the symbols. So if the symbols are 8-bit values, the initial bit size is typically 9. This is just enough for the literal values 0..255 and the first 256 codes from the dictionary. Usually LZW has some special predefined codes, too, like a "Clear" code and a "Stop" code, which are appended to the symbol set as symbols 0x100 and 0x101. They are not strictly required, but quite useful.

Moreover, you have a maximum bit count to limit the growth of the dictionary. In your case, it's 20, so your dictionary can hold up to 1048576 entries. To write variable-length bit codes, you use a register that is wide enough to hold the maximum bit count. In your case, a 32-bit or 64-bit unsigned integer is suitable. (Use the latter if you are targeting a 64-bit processor.) So basically, you maintain a bit shift counter, initially set to 0, and shift/write bits to the register until it overflows. Then you write the entire register to the stream and shift/copy the remaining bits. At the end, you have to flush the latest bits in the register to the stream, if any.

It's really that easy. You don't need any special bit count handling, because the LZW reader and writer have an agreement about when to increase the bit count. Some LZW implementations, like TIFF 6.0 for instance, increase the count BEFORE writing the last code that would fit the old size (so-called "Early Change"). Others (e.g. GIF) increase it AFTERWARDS, which is more efficient. You are free to choose the bit order of the symbols you write. It's just required that the encoder and decoder agree about that. Once again, existing LZW implementations use different bit orders: GIF writes them from least-significant to most-significant, TIFF 6.0 the other way round. The LSB-to-MSB variant is usually more straightforward to implement.

Note that it's a common misconception that the dictionary needs to be cleared as soon as it's full. Actually, I've found that LZW compression is much better in most cases if you just continue with the filled directory, emitting maximum-width codes till the end. This is because the dictionary now reflects the statistical distribution of the input stream and emits efficient codes. A clear is required only if the distribution changes significantly over time, so the dictionary becomes inadequate.

Common LZW decoders for GIF and TIFF frequently clear the dictionary automatically as soon as it's filled up, not waiting for the clear code. This is "bad habit", and even explicitly deprecated in a note accompanying the most recent GIF specification, but alas, it's so common that an encoder should not gamble with the clear code, if it wants to be compatible with all readers.